# How to set back default value to property after using it

Tags: php, oop

I have a `isAccessible` property in my class and it always should be false unless we pass true parameter in access method.

```
class Foo {

    public $isAccessible;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->isAccessible = false;
    }

    public function access($bool){
        $this->isAccessible= $bool;
        return  $this;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $this->isAccessible = false;
    }
}

$class= new Foo;
echo $class->isAccessible // false
$class->access(true)->andsomeothermethods..
// After using access method, it should be false then. 
echo $class->isAccessible // it's shows true but i want it as false
```

How can I do that, is that possible ?

Comment: turn it off again `$class->access(false)->isAccessible`

Comment: What does access method do?  Why do you want to set isAccessible property to false?

Comment: what is "after using it" for you? if you have method that depend on if it's true or false, and if you found that is true and process ... so at the end of the process method call the access again and set it to false.

Comment: `__destruct` is called after no references to the object. That's why when you call `echo $class->isAccessible;` it still shows you `true`.

Comment: @MaximFedorov Well, Foo class actually returns somet other class and it depends isAccesible property.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov could you explain that ? I really don't understand what do you mean with "__destruct is called after no references to the object."

Comment: @HasanTıngır according to [php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) documentation. `PHP 5 introduces a destructor concept similar to that of other object-oriented languages, such as C++. The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set isAccessible property to false after access method ends its work. You can set the necessary value before the return statement

```
class Foo {

    public $isAccessible = false;

    public function access($bool){
        $this->isAccessible = $bool;
        // some code
        $this->isAccessible = false;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

If you want to set isAccessible property to false after calling another method of the class you can set the property in begin of each method

```
class Foo {

    public $isAccessible = false;

    public function access($bool){
        $this->isAccessible = $bool;
        // some code
        return  $this;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->isAccessible = false;
        // some code
        return  $this;        
    }
}
```

Maybe, there is the point use isAccessible only as the parameter of access method.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good approach to change in one method value of the property, do something and at the end of this method chenge this property back. It should be done on purpose, not in one method to tell another dev about that logic. But if you really want to do it on that way do it by using [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)